# Giving error ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P008

Tags: oracle

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P008

ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 408 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 408: '+DATA/maximusp/tempfile/temp.402.dbf'
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.

select cl.cont_no, cl.plan_id, pl.plan_desc, con.eff_date, cl.mbr_no, mem.reg_date, cl.vou_no, PP.prepost_ind, cl.sub_status,cl.adm_date,
cl.process_date, cl.diag_code  from cl_clm_hist_line cl 
inner join mr_contract con on cl.cont_no=con.cont_no
inner join mr_member mem on cl.cont_no||cl.mbr_no=mem.cont_no||mem.mbr_no
inner join bt_plan pl on cl.plan_id=pl.plan_id
inner join cl_clm_hist_vou PP on cl.vou_no=PP.vou_no
where cl.process_date >= '01-Jun-23' and cl.submit_by='M' and pl.plan_desc not like '%MHP%' and PP.prepost_ind <> 'P';
```

Comment: You probably can retry after submitting `ALTER TABLE cl_clm_hist_line NOPARALLEL`  per each table within the query.

Comment: See if the following helps: https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01110_data_file_string.htm

Answer (score 1):

This means the `+DATA/maximusp/tempfile/temp.402.dbf` tempfile does not exist. If you have a DBA, communicate this to them to address it for you. If you are your own DBA, fixing this requires dropping the missing file. Fortunately for temp space there is no data loss involved so this is rather routine.

Most likely your parameter `files=400` which means file 402 is actually tempfile 2:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE temp DROP TEMPFILE 2;
```

Then query `dba_temp_files`. If you get the same error about a different tempfile, drop that one as well, and so on until you get no errors. You may have to create new ones if you have to drop all of them or need the space the dropped files would have provided.

Alternatively, you may have another temporary tablespace available, and if so, you need to change your assigned temporary tablespace to this other one that has all its tempfiles. For example, if the other, good temp space is called `TEMP2`:

```
ALTER USER myusername TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp2;
```

Then retry your query.